# Does a finite $\sup\text{-norm}$ of a function $f_n$ on a domain $S$ imply that the series whose generic term is $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let us start with a generic function $f_n$ on a certain domain $S$. If we know that $||f_n||_{\infty}<C$, where $C$ is a bound such that $C<\infty$, could we state that
$$||f_n||_{\infty}<C\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n \text{ uniformly convergent on }S\tag{1}$$
?

---

If so, why? If not, could you please give/hint a counterexample?

Comment: I think not necessarily. For example each $f_n\equiv 1$. But, you may consider   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: Could things change if I say: $$||f_n||_{\infty}<C\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n \color{red}{\text{ almost surely}}\text{ uniformly convergent on }S$$?

Comment: What do you mean by *almost surely* in this setting?

Comment: Almost everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not, on the contrary there are many counterexamples - even amongst the series of numbers.

Just take $S=\{0\}$ and $f_n(0)=\frac 1n$. Certainly, $f_n$ is bounded, but the series $\sum f_n$ does not converge.

If you want to have a convergence criterium, what you are looking for is so-called *normal* convergence, i.e. $ \sum_n \|f_n\|_\infty$ is a convergent series. This in fact yields uniform convergence of $\sum_n f_n$. The other direction does not hold (uniform convergence of $\sum_n f_n$ does not imply convergence of $\sum_n\|f_n\|_\infty$).

**Edit:** I am adding your example from the comments for clarity. Therefore, let $ a_n = \sqrt{n} 2^{-n/2} $.

First, observe that $\sum a_n$ converges. This can be verified using your favorite convergence criterion for series, i.e., ratio test: $a_{n+1}/a_n=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}2^{-1/2}\to\frac1{\sqrt2}<1$.

If you now have a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ satisfying $\|f_n\|_\infty\le Ca_n$ for some fixed $C>0$ and all (except for finitely many) $n\in\mathbb N$, then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly (because it converges normally, c.f. also the [Weierstrass $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)).

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! *Normal* convergence was exactly what I was looking for, but I didn't know its existence before

Comment: You're welcome. I added the $\infty$ in the indexes of the function norms above, to be precise.

Comment: Pardon, just one last fact:$$||f_n||_{\infty}<C\nRightarrow\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}||f_n||_{\infty}\text{ convergent}$$ right? @Benjamin

Comment: Yes, the counterexamples above show, that the constant $C$ must depend on $n$ for such an implication to hold.

Comment: Maybe I was messing up before, sorry. Now I have edited my last comment above. What I meant is that **finiteness of sup-norm does not imply that the series whose general term is the sup-norm is convergent**. And this is correct, if I understood @Benjamin

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced I had properly "reconstructed" my textbook logic, while doubts arise now. I am told that $C$ is fixed and corresponds to a function of $n$, that is $C=\sqrt{2\ln2}$. Give for granted that there exists a finite $N$ such that $\forall\text{ } n\geq N$:
$$||f_n||_{\infty}<C\sqrt{n}2^{-n/2}$$
"This upper bound implies that, almost surely, the series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n$$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$." I think that normal convergence is used here, but..how can one be sure that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}||f_n||_{\infty}<\infty$ with the disposable info? @Benjamin

Comment: So, question is: why that "[...] upper bound implies [...]" convergence of the series$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n$? Normal convergence establishes:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}||f_n||_{\infty}\text{ convergent }\implies\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n\text{ convergent}$$
However, in this case how does the fact that the general term of the series of $\sup\text{-norm}$ is definitely (from a finite $N$ onwards) bounded automatically imply that series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}||f_n||_{\infty}$ is convergent (then implying that series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n$ is convergent too)? @Benjamin

Comment: I added an example similar to your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Hence, in the end, Weierstrass M-test makes $(1)$ true, keeping in mind normal convergence definition